# In or at the economy

Tags: prepositions

> Low interest rates reflect low cost of borrowing **at** the economy.

Or

> Low interest rates reflect low cost of borrowing **in** the economy.

Which one is better? Or do they convey different meanings?

I believe the 2nd one is better. However, I saw the first sentence in one of the Google results.

Comment: Not everyone who writes English on the internet is a good writer of English.  There are plenty of examples of bad English out there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In" is correct.

"In" is used to say that one thing is contained or encompassed by another. "At" is used when one thing is near or in the vicinity of another.

Something can happen "in" an economy. It can be a part of the economy or a factor in the economy.

I'm hard pressed to think of how something could be "at" an economy. You can't be near an economy or in the vicinity of an economy. There might be some metaphor where this would make sense, but it's not normal use.

"At" can also mean "in the direction of". I just did at Google search for "at the economy" and most of the hits where for "look at the economy", that is, look in the direction of the economy, examine the economy.

Most of the other hits were for "good at the economy", as in, "we need a president who is good at the economy". This is rather informal. Presumably what the writer means is "good at managing the economy". But it's common enough to say that someone is "good at baseball" or "good at chess". In any case, "good at" is something of an idiom, not a literal use of the word "at".